# Error al desplegar un alert , Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) en C#

Tags: javascript, c#

tengo un problema con una cadena de escape que llega en una variable y necesito que se abra un alert con el mensaje de error.

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "<script>Alerta('Error al guardar: No se puedo adjuntar el archivo '" + cerror + " )</script> ");
```

Esta es la linea de codigo en el string me entrega por lo general una cadena

```
string cerror = " Could not find file 'C:\En\DeAPP\Version 1.0 Release 1.0\Web\default.pdf'."
```

les agradeceria si me yudan con esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto agregar @ antes de tu string para escapar las barras invertidas

```
string cerror = @" Could not find file 'C:\En\DeAPP\Version 1.0 Release 1.0\Web\default.pdf'.";
```

Tambien en esta cadena puedes usar interpolacion como alternativa usando $ antes del string y encerrandon entre {} tu variable

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", $"<script>Alerta('Error al guardar: No se puedo adjuntar el archivo ' {cerror} )</script> ");
```